# $http.post success callback is not executing in angularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, mongodb

I am trying to post data in `mongoDb` database using `$http.post()` and calling a success callback. But the callback is not executing neither the data is added to db. I am using `mongodblabs` for hoisting of database.

**Code**

```
if (user) { 
$http.post('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/expensesharer/collections/expensesharer?apiKey=<apikey>', {"id": user.id, "pwd": user.pwd}).success(
  function (data, status, headers) {
      alert("Added", data, status, headers);
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add error callback

```
if (user) { 
    $http.post('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/expensesharer/collections/expensesharer?apiKey=<apikey>', {"id": user.id, "pwd": user.pwd}).success(
    function (data, status, headers) {
        alert("Added", data, status, headers);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Error");
    };  
}
```

Comment: add console.log(user) in if block i think "user" is undefined